# Strtok with Delim issue

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

I am reading a separate `.txt` file and grabbing each line. Then I am using strtok to manipulate each string. I have a #define macro:

```
#define DELIMS "!\"#$%&()|'*+,?/:;<=>@[\092]^_{}~\177\t\ "
```

In the DELIMS I have a space at the very end. When I use this to split up a string, using this in the strtok, it isn't using the space as one of the delims. Am I doing something wrong?

```
void splitLine(char string[], int count)
{
    char *ptr, *word;

  for (ptr = string; word = strtok(ptr, DELIMS); ptr = NULL)
    printf("%s", word);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
define FLUSH while
```

It is displaying the three words in one `printf` instead of displaying each word one at a time.

Comment: `for (word = string; word = strtok(word, DELIMS); word = NULL)`, I see no need for `ptr` or `count`. Though trying to shove all this in the for-sections is a bit over the top don't you think? Certainly isn't adding clarity to the solution. Now how about some sample data, or is it the same [as yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960944/strtok-and-string-manipulation-issues) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes it is the same from yesterday. I am still having issues and thought reposting might get some new input

Comment: Ok, well, you don't have to escape a space in that delim string. I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you.

Comment: that \ you have right before the space at the end of your DELIMS string. it isn't needed.

Comment: I removed it and it's still printing the three words at once instead of one at a time....

Comment: What do you think \092 is?

Comment: You may want to reconsider that and use \\ instead. As it sits now you're prolly unintentionally burying a nullchar \0 in your delimiter list (or so it appears to me). Just for kicks, move the space to the *beginning* of your delim string and try it then.

Comment: I recommend you approach your sources of information critically. The page you have linked may or may not use notation which is compatible with C. Read some C documentation about string literals. If all else fails, try printing `strlen('\092')`.

Comment: So this shows that the documentation for "activePDF" is not a good source of C language information.  Not that I understand why anyone would think that in the first place.